# Spring boot config server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have been trying to get a grip on the spring boot config server that is located Here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config and after reading the documentation more thoroughly I was able to work through most of my issues.  I did however have to write an additional class for a file based PropertySourceLocator

```
/*
 * Copyright 2013-2014 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");


* you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package org.springframework.cloud.config.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

/**
 * @author Al Dispennette
 *
 */
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config")
public class ConfigServiceFilePropertySourceLocator implements PropertySourceLocator {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigServiceFilePropertySourceLocator.class);

    private String env = "default";

    @Value("${spring.application.name:'application'}")
    private String name;

    private String label = name;

    private String basedir = System.getProperty("user.home");

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> locate() {
        try {
            return getPropertySource();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("An error ocurred while loading the properties.",e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private PropertySource getPropertySource() throws IOException {
        Properties source = new Properties();
        Path path = Paths.get(getUri());
        if(Files.isDirectory(path)){
            Iterator<Path> itr = Files.newDirectoryStream(path).iterator();
            String fileName = null!=label||StringUtils.hasText(label)?label:name+".properties";
            logger.info("Searching for {}",fileName);
            while(itr.hasNext()){
                Path tmpPath = itr.next();
                if(tmpPath.getFileName().getName(0).toString().equals(fileName)){
                    logger.info("Found file: {}",fileName);
                    source.load(Files.newInputStream(tmpPath));
                }
            }
        }
        return new PropertiesPropertySource("configService",source);
    }

    public String getUri() {
        StringBuilder bldr = new StringBuilder(basedir)
        .append(File.separator)
        .append(env)
        .append(File.separator)
        .append(name);

        logger.info("loading properties directory: {}",bldr.toString());
        return bldr.toString();
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEnv() {
        return env;
    }

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public String getBasedir() {
        return basedir;
    }

    public void setBasedir(String basedir) {
        this.basedir = basedir;
    }

}
```

Then I added this to the ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java

```
@Bean
public PropertySourceLocator configServiceFilePropertySource(
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment) {
    ConfigServiceFilePropertySourceLocator locator = new ConfigServiceFilePropertySourceLocator();
    String[] profiles = environment.getActiveProfiles();
    if (profiles.length==0) {
        profiles = environment.getDefaultProfiles();
    }
    locator.setEnv(StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(profiles));
    return locator;
}
```

In the end this did what I wanted. 
Now I'm curious to know if this is what I should have done or if I am still missing something and this was already handled and I just missed it.

*****Edit for info asked for by Dave******

If I take out the file property source loader and update the bootstrap.yml with

```
uri: file://${user.home}/resources
```

the sample application throws the following error on start up:

```
ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration : Could not locate PropertySource: Object of class [sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection] must be an instance of class java.net.HttpURLConnection
```

This is why I thought the additional class would be needed.  As far as the test case goes I believe you are talking about the SpringApplicationEnvironmentRepositoryTests.java and I agree creating the environment works but as a whole the application does not seem to be opertaing as expected when the uri protocol is 'file'.

******Additional Edits*******

This is how I understanding this is working:
The sample project has a dependency on the spring-cloud-config-client artifact so therefore has a transitive dependency on the spring-cloud-config-server artifact.
The ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java in the client artifact creates a property source locator bean of type ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.
The ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java in the config client artifact has the annotation @ConfigurationProperties("spring.cloud.config")
And the property uri exists in said class, hence the setting of spring.cloud.config.uri in the bootstrap.yml file.

I believe this is reenforced up by the following statement in the quickstart.adoc:

> When it runs it will pick up the external configuration from the
>   default local config server on port 8888 if it is running. To modify
>   the startup behaviour you can change the location of the config server
>   using `bootstrap.properties` (like `application.properties` but for
>   the bootstrap phase of an application context), e.g.
>
> ### ---- spring.cloud.config.uri: http://myconfigserver.com

At this point, some how the JGitEnvironmentRepository bean is getting used and looking for a connection to github.
I assumed that since uri was the property being set in the ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator then any valid uri protocol would work for pointing to a location.
That is why I used the 'file://' protocol thinking that the server would pick up the NativeEnvironmentRepository.

So at this point I'm sure I'm either missing some step or the file system property source locator needs to be added.

I hope that is a little clearer.

the Full Stack:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class [sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection] must be an instance of class java.net.HttpURLConnection
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:339)
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:319)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.openConnection(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:182)
    at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.createRequest(SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.http.client.support.HttpAccessor.createRequest(HttpAccessor.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:541)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:506)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:448)
    at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.locate(ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator.java:68)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.initialize(ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:70)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:572)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at sample.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

Comment: I guess that depends on what you wanted to achieve. Is this for an app or for a library that other apps will use? In any case you shouldn't have to change `ConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration`, but it's hard to understand what the intention is.

Comment: Hi Dave, The documentation says that I can just change the URI in the bootstrap properties/yaml, so I changed it to use file:///my/file/path.  that gave an error saying that file was not a supported protocol.  In the end what I am looking to achieve is a config server that is shared but the config files live in a folder on the box where the config server is located.  Then the other spring boot apps I create will connect to the cofig server the same way they do when its a git repo. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: The unit tests use "file:" for the remote repository, so it should work. You'd have to show the stack trace or something to diagnose the problem. Note also that unless the file system is shared you will have a SPOF.

Comment: Hi @DaveSyer , Was the edit in the main post enough information or would you like something more?

Comment: That's not actually a stack trace. And the config file is not a spring cloud config file ("uri" is not bound to anything in the config server out of the box anyway). Maybe you can expand a bit?

Comment: Your "bootstrap.yml" snippet just says `uri`. So you set `spring.cloud.config.uri` in "bootstrap.yml" of the config server? Or of the client? I'm confused, and your description of the transitive dependencies is upside down: the server depends on the client not the other way round, and `spring.cloud.config.uri` is a client setting, not a server setting. The client should not need to know about git.

Comment: I updated the sample application bootstrap.yml "<artifactId>spring-cloud-config-sample</artifactId>" I apologize about the uri thing being confusing I thought there was enough other info that I didn't need to type out the entire property key.  as far as the transitive dependency yes I misstated that. Also in testing I did add a bootstrap.yml to the config server artifact to see what would happen and it resulted in the same exception. I really wish there was a better way to communicate that this as well.

Comment: I am pretty sure the class I wrote is needed.  Because the ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator assumes that a RestTemplate is needed to get properties files.

Comment: So the clients have a local config file (not the server)? Then it's normal Spring Boot rules, and all you need is to set `spring.config.location` for each of the clients. You can do that without even using Spring Cloud, but `bootstrap.yml` is fine if you are using Cloud. The best way to communicate is to create a sample project and publish it somewhere with complete instructions and/or tests. If you can do that it might be easier to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63885/discussion-between-peekay-and-dave-syer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have the final solution based on your last comments
In the configserver.yml I added

```
spring.profiles.active: file
spring.cloud.config.server.uri: file://${user.home}/resources
```

In the ConfigServerConfiguration.java I added

```
@Configuration
@Profile("file")
protected static class SpringApplicationConfiguration {
@Value("${spring.cloud.config.server.uri}")
String locations;

@Bean
public SpringApplicationEnvironmentRepository repository() {
SpringApplicationEnvironmentRepository repo = new SpringApplicationEnvironmentRepository();
repo.setSearchLocations(locations);
return repo;
}
}
```

And I was able to view the properties with:

```
curl localhost:8888/bar/default
curl localhost:8888/foo/development
```

Answer (score 6):

I read this thread yesterday and it was missing a vital piece of information

If you don't want to use git as a repository, then you need to configure the spring cloud server to have spring.profiles.active=native

Checkout the spring-config-server code to understand it
org.springframework.cloud.config.server.NativeEnvironmentRepository

```
 spring:
   application:
    name: configserver
  jmx:
    default_domain: cloud.config.server
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        file :
          url : <path to config files>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just came cross same issue. I want the configuration server load properties from local file system instead of git repository. The following configuration works for me on windows.

```
spring:  
  profiles:
    active: native
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        native: 
          searchLocations: file:C:/springbootapp/properties/
```

Suppose the property file is under C:/springbootapp/properties/

For more information please refer to [Spring Cloud Documentation](http://projects.spring.io/spring-cloud/spring-cloud.html) and [Configuring It All Out](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/13/configuring-it-all-out-or-12-factor-app-style-configuration-with-spring)